# Java MVC Model View Dao Separation

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I would like to optimise my Java programming code towards a better separation of model and view.

At the moment I have Panels which represent the view and POJOs and DAOs representing the model.

Is it possible to separate the model component DaoUser from the View Panel?

```
// Panel User
class UserPanel extends JPanel{
   DaoUser daoUser = new DaoUser;
   User user = daoUser.findUser(current_id);
   JTextField tf = new JTextField();
   tf.setText(user.getName());
}

//POJO User
class User{
 int id;
 String name;

Getters and Setters ..
}

// Dao User
class DaoUser{
 public void saveUser(User user)
 public User findUsers();
 public List<User> listUsers()

}
```

Comment: Yes, by adding a manager/controller layer. Btw, a better name for DaoUser would be UserDAO.

Comment: *"Is it possible to separate the model component DaoUser from the View Panel?"* - Yes.  Simply pass an instance of `DoaUser` to `UserPanel` rather the creating an instance of it.  Also you really should be making use of `interfaces` over classes to describe the expected behaviour

Comment: Use one of the observer patterns suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Comment: A question... the MVC pattern lets you to update the view if your model changes... in this case, what's your change??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would do something like this:

```
class DaoUser extends Observable {
  //other methods
  public User findUsers (int id_user) {
    //find your user. Once you find it
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(user_found);
  }
}
```

and in your view, you should do:

```
class UserPanel extends JPanel implements Observer {
  tf = new JTextField();
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object ob) {
  User u=(User) ob;
  tf.setText(u.getName());
}
```

I hope this could help you